# Change CLI PHP version on Mac

Tags: php, macos, bitnami

I using Mac BigSur lastest update.
I have install Bitnami MAPP with PHP version 8.0.8.
But in CLI still PHP 7.3.24

I try create PATH to Bitnami PHP8.0.8 but have warning like below

```
WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: Dec 21 2020 21:33:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

How to switch PHP CLI to PHP8.0.8 of Bitnami?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami engineer here!

The output you are seeing is produced by the PHP binary that comes preinstalled in macOS. When you install Bitnami MAMP, a standalone, updated version of PHP will also be installed in your system. In order to use it instead of the default one, you have two options:

1. Use the full path to the binary (`installdir/php/bin/php`)

```
$ /Applications/mampstack-8.0.9-0/php/bin/php --version
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2021 07:59:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

2. Add the directory containing the PHP binary to your path

```
$ export PATH=/Applications/mampstack-8.0.9-0/php/bin:$PATH
$php --version
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 30 2021 07:59:45) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

For the examples above, `/Applications/mampstack-8.0.9-0` was the installation directory (`installdir`) of the stack.

Comment: Thanks @Jose.
Yes, `which php` command help me out to know which php engine working on CLI mode. And then switch it to the correct one.